# Magnific Popu get data attribute and put it in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Need help in getting data attribute and put it in a variable to be used in markup.  The attribute is "data-mydesc"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

html

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
                     <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="bigpic1.png" title="pic1 title" data-mydesc="this is a description1"> <img id="png1" 

src="pic1.png"></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="bigpic2.png" title="pic2 title" data-mydesc="this is a description2"> <img id="png1" 

src="pic2.png"></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="bigpic3.png" title="pic3 title" data-mydesc="this is a description3"> <img id="png1" 

src="pic3.png"></a>
                     </li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
                $('.thumbnails').magnificPopup({
                    type:'image',
                    delegate: '.image-additional a:visible',
                    image: {
                markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                        '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+ 
                        '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                        '<div class="data-mydesc"></div>'+ 
                    '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                            '</div>', 
                 cursor: 'mfp-zoom-out-cur',
                  tError: '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.'
                  },
                  preloader: true,
                    gallery: {
                        enabled:true
                    }

                });
```

Comment: What's the current behaviour of the program that is not the expected one?

Comment: i cannot get the attribute value of data-mydesc